# Dissociate Searchbar from TableView in UIViewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I try to separate a tableview from its searchbar. Is it possible to add a Searchbar in a UIView (xib file / storyboard) at one place of a viewcontroller, then add a containerview targeting a tableview at an other place of the UIView and then linking both to have them working together as if we had added the searchbar directly a tableviewcontroller?

I need to have some space between my searchbar and my first row of the tableview to insert labels that have to stay in place without being thrown away when scrolling down...

The searchbar is working properly when inserted directly inside the tableviewcontroller. Ideally I just would like to insert a new object (the searchbar) and connecting it (delegate,...) to the tableviewcontroller inside the containerview.

Is it possible? Something like the image below...

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I am suggesting you to use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, UIViewController can add multiple views and space b/w views, Difficult do it with UITableViewController.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not understood. I have a UIViewController to be able to insert some space. The problem is that I don't know how I can connect the searchbar in the uiviewcontroller to the tableviewcontroller. Could me explain me what you mean?

Comment: Don't use the table view controller.  A regular UIViewController that has a UITableView in it works just as well.  In it you can arrange the view hierarchy however you like.

Comment: You mean I should move all my method inside tableviewcontroller to UIViewcontroller and then referecing the datasource, delegate and serachbar delegate to it?

Comment: I still cannot figure out how I can add a Searchbar with interface buidler and connect it to my tableview. All the tutorials are saying that it should be done programmatically, but I dont want to have it located in a header. But really elsewhere in the UIView. Is it possible?